# Unable to get equal spaced margins on a webpage

Tags: html, css

I have three boxes/containers on a single row of my webpage.

The first box, the blue box is 2px away from the browser edge on the left, while the last box, the purple box is 2px when I inspect element.

[image of boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT3Ld.png)

However it does not look like this on the web page and looks uneven:

http://jamesbsite-com.stackstaging.com/

I have read all about the box-model but I am still unable to get equal spacing even though I have set a 2px margin on both the left and right.

Please advise as to what is causing this?
The .call-outs-container is the parent container and the .call-out is the child
and they are being applied to these divs:

#

amendment

complete code below

#

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>James' page!</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <style type="text/css">

    hr {height:1px; border:none; color:#000; background-color:#000;}

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }


        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        a:visited{
            color:green;
        }

        body { margin: 0;}


           .ClearFloat {  
                clear: both;  
            }  



            .call-outs-container 
            {
                max-width: 2000px; 
                margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px 
            }

            .call-out {

                padding: 5px;
                margin-left: 2px; margin-top: 40px; margin-right: 2px;        margin-bottom: -5px;;
                width:30%;
                float:left;
            }


            .call-out:nth-child(1) {background-color: #c0dbe2;}
            .call-out:nth-child(2) {background-color: #cdf1c3;}
            .call-out:nth-child(3) {background-color: #ccb9da;}
            .call-out:nth-child(5) {background-color: #c0dbe2;}


            .box{
                 border:10px solid #CC3F85;
                 width:400px;
                 margin: 0 auto;
                 padding: 20px;
             }

    </style>


    </head>

    <body>
<iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NkyEOrQiGMQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"  allowfullscreen target = "test1"></iframe>

 <div class="call-outs-container">
            <div class="call-out">
                <h4>Feature1</h4>
                <p> hello</p>
            </div>

      <div class="call-out">
          <h4>Feature2</h4>
           <p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2wFsu_O490">Nanking</a></p>
           <p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2wFsu_O490" target="_blank">new tab</a></p>
      </div>

        <div class="call-out">
            <h4>Feature3</h4>
            I am interested in history.
        </div>

        <div class = "ClearFloat"></div>

        <div class="call-out">
            <h1>James's page!</h1>
       </div>
</div>

<div class = "ClearFloat"></div>

<h2>A few facts about me</h2>

<img src="me.jpeg" width="400">

<p>I like web desigm.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't really see the issue here. The picture and the webpage look the same to me. The only suggestion I could make is that the effective margin on the left is 3px, since the 1px margin of the container is being added to the 2px callout margin.

Comment: Are you wanting 2px of space between the boxes, and the container?

Comment: the code you supplied doesn't match the picture link.  That being said, you probably want to use flexbox here.  Show your actual code (complete) and I'll help you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: @Jon P : I have edited above with full code now.

Comment: @Lawrence Witt : I shall try to replace the image to show how it is appearing to me.Thank you for your suggestion, but that also holds true for why the right is effectively a 3px margin and when I inspected the page the box-model showed so too, yet it does not look evenly spaced on the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
text-align:center;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 300px;

  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  
  float: right;
  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>Welcome Page</div>

<div>Welcome Page2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter "bro". Explain what you are doing and why it solves his problem. This isn't reddit. Be  a professional. [answer]

Comment: @Rob perhaps try and provide constructive feedback with less [condescension and more professionalism](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). You raise valid points in that a good answer explains how it address the problem with text and/or comments. The delivery is somewhat lacking though.

Comment: @JonP Don't try and make this problem about me. Stick with the issue instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using flexbox in this situation. It will make controlling things much easier. No need for `float`.

1. First, you need to add `display: flex` to `.call-outs-container`.
2. Next, specify that the items will fill the axis evenly by adding `flex: 1 1 0` to `.call-out`

```css
.call-outs-container {
  display: flex;
}

.call-out {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  /* margin-left: 2px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  width: 30%;
  float: left; */
}

.call-out:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #c0dbe2;
}

.call-out:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #cdf1c3;
}

.call-out:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #ccb9da;
}
```

```html
<div class="call-outs-container">
  <div class="call-out">
    <h4>Feature1</h4>
    <p> hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="call-out">
    <h4>Nanking</h4>
    new tab
  </div>
  <div class="call-out">
    <h4>Feature3</h4>
    I am interested in history.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already know how to solve in Flexbox and I am trying to understand floats in depth therefore I would like to know what the problem is - why there is more whitespace extending from the right of the last box , the purple one to the browser edge than there  is extending from the left of the light-blue/greyish 1st box to the browser edge.

Comment: @kim28 Why you would want to use floats over flexbox is a mystery to me. But the reason you are seeing a gap at the end is because the width of each element is only 30%. 3x30% = 90% so 10% minus the margins is not filled. Flexbox solves this problem automatically.

Comment: I changed the    .call-outs-container to

                max-width: 1800px;
and
.call-out {
                padding: 1px;
                margin-left: 1px;
                margin-top: 40px;
                margin-right: 1px;
                width:400px;
                float:left;

they stillnot on same row, my arithmetic shows should be:
1800 -  (pad 1+margin-left 1 marginRight+1+width:400 )*3   = 1800-1527
= 273 pixels of room for the three boxes to be on the same row yet 3rd (feature3) is on a new line